# httpDelete Async Task #4

Tags: java, android, node.js, android-asynctask

Here is my doInBackground func:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            if(type.equals("POST") || type.equals("PUT")){
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", pid));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
            }else if(type.equals("DELETE")){
                Log.d("DELETE:", pid);
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", pid));
            }
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url, type, params);
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            if(type.equals("GET")){
                try {
                    jsonRows = json.getJSONArray("rows");
                    for(int i = 0; i<jsonRows.length();i++){
                        JSONObject p = (JSONObject)jsonRows.get(i);
                        aList.add(p.getString("ID") + " - " +p.getString("Name"));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                try{
                    String result = json.getString("results");
                    return result;
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

my httpDelete code :

```
else if(method == "DELETE"){
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String param = null;
            for (NameValuePair nvp : params){
                param = nvp.getValue();
                url += "/" + param;
                Log.d("url = ", url);
            }

            HttpDelete httpDelete = new HttpDelete(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpDelete);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
```

and node.js server :

```
app.delete('/api/db/:id', function(req, res){

var id = req.params.id;
res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
dbPool.getConnection(function(objErr, objConn){
    if(objErr){
        sendError(res, 503, 'error', 'connection', objErr); //503 - Service Unavailable
    }else{
        objConn.query("DELETE FROM person WHERE ID = ? ",[id], function(Err, Rows, Fields){
            if(Err){
                sendError(res, 500, 'error', 'query', Err);
            }else{
                res.send({
                    results : 'success'
                });
                objConn.release();
                gcmSend();
            }//else
        });
    }//else
});
});
```

Errors:

```
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground() 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 36: -----192.168.1.11:3030/api/db/9  
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete.<init>(HttpDelete.java:68) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at com.argenit.monitor.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:86) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at com.argenit.monitor.MainPage$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainPage.java:137) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at com.argenit.monitor.MainPage$HttpAsyncTask.doInBackground(MainPage.java:1) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 
09-24 06:35:12.386: E/AndroidRuntime(1908):     ... 4 more
```

Anyone help me?

Last logcat before error :

> Log.d("url = ", url); -> 09-24 06:40:45.066: D/url =(1978):
>   ----/192.168.1.11:3030/api/db/8

Comment: Have you tried new HttpDelete(URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8"));

Comment: Just use this `urUrl.replace(" ","%20");`

Comment: also, if recall it correctly the scheme is compulsory

Comment: i tried new HttpDelete(URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")); and url.replace(" ","%20"); but problem not solved, same error continue

Comment: Your problem quite simple. As per your question you have some extra character in your string which is not valid. so above both comment must be work. Though just check it again.

Comment: yes, i checked again and logcat gave different error : 09-24 06:52:36.036: E/AndroidRuntime(2199): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=http://192.168.1.11:3030/api/db/7+     BUT my url has not "+" character, how?

Comment: Log cat : url =(2283): http://192.168.1.11:3030/api/db/8          
      url =(2283): http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.11%3A3030%2Fapi%2Fdb%2F8+   (((( Log.d("url = ", url); Log.d("url = ", URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")); )))

Comment: @Touregsys At in ur url some parameter goes null or ur url is incomplete and check your host name also. And looks like your using local api url then you have to run your app in Emulator instead of real device.

Comment: i run in Emulator. Post,put,get methods work well but delete gives me an error. my url looks true, i will check again

Comment: @PG_Android i used url.trim() and works. But i dont understand why it didnt work, why it worked :))